# mysql preparedStatement : sql query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, glassfish, prepared-statement

I have a preparedStatement for select query in mySQL.

this is what I wrote:

```
 String sQuery = "SELECT Password FROM test WHERE Email = ?";
 st = DB.prepareStatement(sQuery);
 st.setString(1, email);
 ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery(sQuery);
```

but i'm getting an exception from the glassfish server that says:

```
Severe:   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

I don't understand what is the problem.. all the samples i saw, use that syntax..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must call `st.executeQuery()`, without the query as argument. The query has already been passed to the statement when it was prepared.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29

Comment: its weird.. netbeans didn't show me an error.. thanks :)

Comment: Because PreparedStatement inherits from Statement, and thus also allows executing a SQL query without preparing it.

Comment: OK :) thanks.. i don't believe that this is was the cause.. :)
anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`st.executeQuery()` i.e. **no param to executeQuery**